Alpine 3d 3cd changer magazines. 3d print plans?
I have a old Alpine head unit 7983r that uses Alpine 3d shuttle magazines. (Alpine model 4907). They are hard to come by, or expensive. They have been used in Volvo cars too at early 2000s, maybe other makers too. Is there a plans to 3d print the magazine, or is it how feasible? Thank you.
